# PHP - strtotime is ignoring the year

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
$date_string = "1 October, 2013";
$date_time = strtotime($date_string); //evaluates to "1412208780"
$date_string_again = date("m/d/y", $date_time); //evaluates to "10/01/14" .. should be "10/01/13"
```

Why is my code giving me the wrong year? How do I fix it?

Comment: Remove the comma in `$date_string`, you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes you can not have comma.

Comment: `Why is my code giving me the wrong year?` : because `2013` part of your date string is parsed as time, like `20:13`. And because no year was fetched, current year is applied. If you format your `$date_time` as `Y-m-d H:i`, you would get `2014-10-01 20:13`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the comma is throwing it off. Remove it!

```
$date_string = "1 October, 2013";
$date_string = str_replace(',','',$date_string);
$date_time = strtotime($date_string); 
$date_string_again = date("m/d/y", $date_time);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make use of [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php
$dt = '1 October, 2013';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F, Y', $dt);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); //"prints" 10/01/2013
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not a valid format that `strtotime()` recognizes, see the manual for [accepted formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If the format is fixed like this, you could use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to convert your date to a DateTime object.